# Add an additional field for creating an article (Joomla)?

Tags: joomla, overriding, article

I would like to expand the standard component for creating a new article (com_content) in Joomla with an additional field.
I did an template override and added the field in the UI. But I do not know how I can add the value to the database. Which file do I have to change? Is this possible with an template override?

Comment: The easiest thing is to make one of the existing field declarations into a `fields` declaration (in the XML) and then enclose both fields in that. THis waill automatically save both fields in the single database field using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a content plugin and catch `onContentPrepareForm()` event.

There is a step by step tutorial for that: [Adding custom fields to the article component](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component).

A more general tutorial for adding fields to core components could be found at: [Adding custom fields to core components using a plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin).